# Zebra RFD2000 TC20 RFID SDK

Tags: android, sdk, rfid

I am using the quick start example supplied in the Android developer guide (rfid-sdk-for-android-dg-en.pdf) and although it does work and scans RFID TAGS there seems to be a problem with the reliability of the scanning. I have tracked the problem down to the EventHandler Class, that the reader.Actions.getReadTags method sometimes returns null this is even if the RFID tags are next to the scanner.

Any help would be much appreciated

I have included the code that I am using:

```
package uk.co.assettrac.rfd2000_tc20_example;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.zebra.rfid.api3.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static Readers readers;
    private static ArrayList<ReaderDevice> availableRFIDReaderList;
    private static ReaderDevice readerDevice;
    private static RFIDReader reader;
    private static String TAG = "DEMO";
    TextView textView;
    private EventHandler eventHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
// UI
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TagText);
// SDK
        if (readers == null) {
            readers = new Readers(this, ENUM_TRANSPORT.SERVICE_SERIAL);
        }
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    if (readers != null) {
                        if (readers.GetAvailableRFIDReaderList() != null) {
                            availableRFIDReaderList =
                                    readers.GetAvailableRFIDReaderList();
                            if (availableRFIDReaderList.size() != 0) {
// get first reader from list
                                readerDevice = availableRFIDReaderList.get(0);
                                reader = readerDevice.getRFIDReader();
                                if (!reader.isConnected()) {
// Establish connection to the RFID Reader
                                    reader.connect();
                                    ConfigureReader();
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InvalidUsageException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OperationFailureException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, "OperationFailureException " + e.getVendorMessage());
                }
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
                super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
                if (aBoolean) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reader Connected",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//textView.setText("Reader connected");
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    private void ConfigureReader() {
        if (reader.isConnected()) {
            TriggerInfo triggerInfo = new TriggerInfo();
            triggerInfo.StartTrigger.setTriggerType(START_TRIGGER_TYPE.START_TRIGGER_TYPE_IMMEDIATE);
            triggerInfo.StopTrigger.setTriggerType(STOP_TRIGGER_TYPE.STOP_TRIGGER_TYPE_IMMEDIATE);
            try {
// receive events from reader
                if (eventHandler == null)
                    eventHandler = new EventHandler();
                reader.Events.addEventsListener(eventHandler);
// HH event
                reader.Events.setHandheldEvent(true);
// tag event with tag data
                reader.Events.setTagReadEvent(true);
                reader.Events.setAttachTagDataWithReadEvent(true);
// set trigger mode as rfid so scanner beam will not come
                reader.Config.setTriggerMode(ENUM_TRIGGER_MODE.RFID_MODE, true);
// set start and stop triggers
                reader.Config.setStartTrigger(triggerInfo.StartTrigger);
                reader.Config.setStopTrigger(triggerInfo.StopTrigger);
            } catch (InvalidUsageException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OperationFailureException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.Events.removeEventsListener(eventHandler);
                reader.disconnect();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disconnecting reader",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                reader = null;
                readers.Dispose();
                readers = null;
            }
        } catch (InvalidUsageException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationFailureException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Read/Status Notify handler
// Implement the RfidEventsLister class to receive event notifications
    public class EventHandler implements RfidEventsListener {
        // Read Event Notification
        public void eventReadNotify(RfidReadEvents e) {
// Recommended to use new method getReadTagsEx for better performance in case of large tag population
            TagData[] myTags = reader.Actions.getReadTags(100);
            if (myTags != null) {
                for (int index = 0; index < myTags.length; index++) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Tag ID " + myTags[index].getTagID());
                    if (myTags[index].getOpCode() ==
                            ACCESS_OPERATION_CODE.ACCESS_OPERATION_READ &&
                            myTags[index].getOpStatus() ==
                                    ACCESS_OPERATION_STATUS.ACCESS_SUCCESS) {
                        if (myTags[index].getMemoryBankData().length() > 0) {
                            Log.d(TAG, " Mem Bank Data " + myTags[index].getMemoryBankData());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "TagData Array Null");
            }
        }
        // Status Event Notification
        public void eventStatusNotify(RfidStatusEvents rfidStatusEvents) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Status Notification: " +
                    rfidStatusEvents.StatusEventData.getStatusEventType());
            if (rfidStatusEvents.StatusEventData.getStatusEventType() ==
                    STATUS_EVENT_TYPE.HANDHELD_TRIGGER_EVENT) {
                if
                        (rfidStatusEvents.StatusEventData.HandheldTriggerEventData.getHandheldEvent() ==
                        HANDHELD_TRIGGER_EVENT_TYPE.HANDHELD_TRIGGER_PRESSED) {
                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                            try {
                                reader.Actions.Inventory.perform();
                            } catch (InvalidUsageException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (OperationFailureException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                    }.execute();
                }

                if (rfidStatusEvents.StatusEventData.HandheldTriggerEventData.getHandheldEvent() ==
                        HANDHELD_TRIGGER_EVENT_TYPE.HANDHELD_TRIGGER_RELEASED) {
                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                            try {
                                reader.Actions.Inventory.stop();
                            } catch (InvalidUsageException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (OperationFailureException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                    }.execute();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to complete it?

Answer (score 2):

After reading the docs for a long time I found that the line

reader.Events.setAttachTagDataWithReadEvent(true);

was causing the problem.